# trying to use vb.net to upload file to sinatra

Tags: ruby, vb.net, sinatra, file-transfer

I am trying to use VB.Net to upload a file to a Sinatra web service, and I'm not sure how to configure either end.  When I run the VB.Net app, sinatra invariably responds with code 404.  Here's the VB.Net code, which I converted from another SO post:

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
     Dim responseData As String = ""
     Dim rdr As FileStream = New FileStream("X:\QueryTxtFiles\Query\CDA Curncy_9_1_2011.fqy", FileMode.Open)
     Dim req As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("http://finqueryserver:9898"), HttpWebRequest)
     req.Method = "POST" ' you might use "POST"
     req.ContentLength = rdr.Length
     req.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = True   

     Dim reqStream = DirectCast(req.GetRequestStream(), Stream)

     Dim inData(rdr.Length) As Byte

     ' Get data from upload file to inData 
     Dim bytesRead As Integer = rdr.Read(inData, 0, rdr.Length)

     ' put data into request stream
     reqStream.Write(inData, 0, rdr.Length)

     rdr.Close()
     Try
         req.GetResponse()
     Catch ex As Exception
         responseData = "An error occurred: " & ex.Message
     End Try

     ' after uploading close stream 
     reqStream.Close()
 End Sub
```

And here is the Sinatra code:

```
 require 'rubygems'
 require 'sinatra'

 post '/:name/:filename' do
puts "got here"

   begin
     name = params[:name]
   rescue
     name = "no name"
   end  
   begin
     filename = params[:filename]
   rescue
     filename = "no filename"
   end  
 end
```

(I never see "got here".)The Sinatra code is based on tutorials using cURL, which I am not.  I've also tried

```
 post "/:filename'
```

which gives 404 also, and simply

```
 post "/"
```

which does show "got here", but is obviously useless because I need to deal with the file.

Clearly I'm a newbie at both, this can't be that hard, but I'm not sure what to do.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, well for posterity, here's what I did to get it to work.  In the vb.net code, I used:

```
  qry_results = wc.UploadFile("http://192.168.9.81:9898/execfqy", "X:\QueryTxtFiles\Query\CDA Curncy_9_1_2011.fqy")
```

and in the sinatra file:

```
 post '/execfqy' do
 qry_file.write(params[:file][:tempfile].readlines)
```